# creating class instance counter and updating it

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

below is python code which counts the number of times the Employee class was created and saves this value as self.id
why do we use Employee.new_id instead of self.new_id or just simply new_id when assigning or updating a class variable

```
class Employee:
  new_id = 1

  def __init__(self):
    self.id = Employee.new_id
    Employee.new_id += 1
```

I tried changing the first line to self.new_id and it works well, but if I update the second line to that too it keeps the counter at 1

Answer (score 0):

The name `new_id` is not understood within the context of `__init__()` so to give in context we need the class name as well as it is a class member.

The instance member `self.id` is specific to each instance of `Employee()` and gets assigned the "current" value of the class variable which is then incremented.

so this:

```py
class Employee:
  new_id = 1

  def __init__(self):
    self.id = Employee.new_id
    Employee.new_id += 1

e1 = Employee()
print(f"Emp #1 ID: {e1.id} Next ID: {Employee.new_id}")

e2 = Employee()
print(f"Emp #1 ID: {e1.id} Emp #2 ID: {e2.id} Next ID: {Employee.new_id}")
```

Give us:

```
Emp #1 ID: 1 Next ID: 2
Emp #1 ID: 1 Emp #2 ID: 2 Next ID: 3
```

The class member `Employee.new_id` conceptually storing the "next" instance's value for `id`.

Comment: Hello, great explanation, but i don't understand why we can't use self.new_id instead of Employee.new_id when we come to update the variable new_id

Comment: `self.new_id` can be updated, but that value is specific to each instance of the class. In order to maintain the value of the "next" id to assign when the next instance of the class is constructed, we need something outside the context of the instance. Put a second way, how would a new employee `e3` get it's proper id from the instance `e1`?